# Jenkins IOS App Getting failed FATAL: No global development team or local team ID was configured

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using Jenkins for IOS apps from long back, It was working good before,
But Recently I am getting one issue, I am not able to fix the issue. 
What might be the issue, Does anybody fixed this issue[image].

I am getting below error

**FATAL: No global development team or local team ID was configured.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Xcode 8.3 onward xcrun command in removed support from Xcode.
So, It's trying to run all commands like validation and build process using xcrun.

That is the reason its failed, We tried with changing Development TeamID as well, But didn't work for us. 
Then we downgraded to XCode 8.2, then started working.
 Until unless fix comes from Jenkins plugin we will face issues like this.

Comment: I've fixed it with this PR...waiting for it to be accepted, but it works if you want to build it or use the snapshot. https://github.com/jenkinsci/xcode-plugin/pull/78

Answer (score 11):

We have a similar problem after we updated xcode and jenkin to the latest build. My team lead fixed it by setting the team id in jenkin's configuration setting. Your team id can be found in your profile overview after you login your apple developer account.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should add the development team ID as @xiaowoo told before. And don't forget to setup the **Export Method** in the General Build Settings!

[image]